# Configuring subfigures within a tabular environment

Tags: tabularx, multirow, subcaption

I am trying to configure a table of subfigures (including multirow commands) within a tabular environment, however the result gives me an odd blank space above the mutlirow figure to the right. I have begun and ended the document with the appropriate userpackages. I have additional subfigures on the page before and after attached with the \ContinuedFloat command. Any help with this would be amazing! Note that this is for a geological masters project for reference.

Code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Annotated stratigraphy at site RKBS9.}
\label{fig:RKBS9_site}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_slope_sq.pdf}
\caption{Overview of site 9, indicating positions of detailed pictures.}
\label{fig:RKBS9_slope}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat

\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_top_sq2.pdf}
    \caption{Upper cover-bed stratigraphy.}
    \label{fig:RKBS9_top}
\end{subfigure} 
& \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_out_sq2.pdf}
    \caption{Contact between Breccas 2 and 1, with the interbedded Hinemaiaia Tephra.}
    \label{fig:RKBS9_out}
\end{subfigure}} \\
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_paleosol_sq2.pdf}
    \caption{Paleosol separating Breccia 3 (upper) and Breccia 2 (lower).}
    \label{fig:RKBS9_close}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_longbomb.pdf}
\caption{Detailed view of contact between Breccia 2 and 1, with a bomb sag indicting the violent 
impact ballistics preceding the deposition of Breccia 2.}
\label{fig:RKBS9_longbomb}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
```

The output of the subfigure table (excluding figures on other pages):

[image]

Comment: Any news? Does my answer fulfill your expectation. If yes, you may consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

With help of `valign` macro from the `adjustbox` package (which also load `graphicx`) you can move baseline the first image in table and image in `multirow˛cell on their top:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo,  % in real document remove this option!
            export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Annotated stratigraphy at site RKBS9.}
\label{fig:RKBS9_site}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth] {Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_slope_sq.pdf}
\caption{Overview of site 9, indicating positions of detailed pictures.}
\label{fig:RKBS9_slope}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t] {Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_top_sq2.pdf}
    \caption{Upper cover-bed stratigraphy.}
    \label{fig:RKBS9_top}
\end{subfigure} & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=1.1\linewidth, valign=t] {Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_out_sq2.pdf}
    % in real document remove `height` option or adjust to desired value
    \caption{Contact between Breccas 2 and 1, with the interbedded Hinemaiaia Tephra.}
    \label{fig:RKBS9_out}
\end{subfigure}} \\
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width= \linewidth] {Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_paleosol_sq2.pdf}
    \caption{Paleosol separating Breccia 3 (upper) and Breccia 2 (lower).}
    \label{fig:RKBS9_close}
\end{subfigure}    &
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width= \linewidth] {Figures/Study_Site/Outcrops/RKBS9_longbomb.pdf}
\caption{Detailed view of contact between Breccia 2 and 1, with a bomb sag indicting the violent impact ballistics preceding the deposition of Breccia 2.}
\label{fig:RKBS9_longbomb}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]